Iterated rascal triangle row sums
In this manuscript the authors propose the following conjecture (1)
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \binom{4i+3}{k}_i &= 2^{4i+2}
\end{align*}
where $\binom{4i+3}{k}_i$ is iterated rascal number defined as
\begin{align*}
    \binom{n}{k}_i &= \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{n-k}{m} \binom{k}{m}
\end{align*}
So that conjecture (1) can be expressed in terms of binomial coefficients (2)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{m} = 2^{4i+2}
$$
My approach
To prove the conjecture (1)
I utilize relations in terms of binomial coefficients and iterated rascal numbers.
Recall the row sums property of binomial coefficients
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \binom{4i+3}{k} = 2^{4i+3}
\end{equation*}
If conjecture (1) is true, then it is also true that
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \binom{4i+3}{k} -  \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \binom{4i+3}{k}_i = 2^{4i+2}
\end{equation*}
because $2^{4i+3} - 2^{4i+2} = 2^{4i+2}$.
Expanding both sums applying Vandermonde convolution $\binom{a+b}{r} = \sum_{m=0}^{r} \binom{a}{m} \binom{b}{r-m}$ we get
\begin{align*}
2^{4i+2} &= \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} - \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}\\
2^{4i+2} &= \sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} - \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}
\end{align*}
Note that $\binom{n}{k} \geq \binom{n}{k}_i$ for each $n,k,i$.
Now we have three possible relations between $i,k$: $k < i$, $k = i$, $k > i$.
If $k < i$ then inner sums equal zero
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} - \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}
= 0
\end{equation*}
Because $\binom{k}{k-m}$ in the sum over $i$ is zero for all $m > k$.
If $k = i$ obviously
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} - \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} = 0
\end{equation*}
If $k > i$ then
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m} - \sum_{m=0}^{i} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}
= \sum_{m=i+1}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have to prove that
\begin{equation*}
2^{4i+2} = \sum_{k} \sum_{m=i+1}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{m} \binom{k}{k-m}
\end{equation*}
Let $m$ to iterate from 0
\begin{equation*}
2^{4i+2} = \sum_{k} \sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{i+1+m} \binom{k}{i+1+m}
\end{equation*}
Although, above equation almost exactly matches Vandermonde identity, it cannot be applied directly.
Even it were applied, the result would disprove the main conjecture giving $2^{4i+3}$ as row sums.
My validations show that indeed conjecture true for $i \leq 100$.
Therefore, propose the following conjecture:
Conjecture 2.1 For every $i$
\begin{equation*}
    2^{4i+2} = \sum_{k} \sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{4i+3-k}{i+1+m} \binom{k}{i+1+m}
\end{equation*}
Above conjecture validated up to $i=100$.
Mathematica scripts I used to validate all conjectures can be found on GitHub
Statement of the problem: It can be either a tip, a correction of my proof, or your own perspective

Are you asking for a proof check on your approach?

It can be either a tip, a correction of my proof, or your own perspective. I just too interested to see why this identity holds

A variation: We use the coefficient of operator to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{4i+3}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{m=0}^i\binom{4i+3-k}{m}\binom{k}{m}}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\binom{4i+3-k}{m}\binom{k}{m}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{4i+3-k-m}{m}\binom{k+m}{m}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[z^m](1+z)^{4i+3-k-m}\binom{-m-1}{k}(-1)^k\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i[z^m](1+z)^{4i+3-m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{-m-1}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(1+z)^k}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i[z^m](1+z)^{4i+3-m}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{-m-1}\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i[z^{2m+1}](1+z)^{4i+4}\tag{6}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^i\binom{4i+4}{2m+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=0}^{2i+1}\binom{4i+4}{2m+1}
=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=0}^{4i+4}\binom{4i+4}{m}\tag{7}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{4i+2}}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.

Comment:

In (2) we set the upper limit of the inner sum to $\infty$ which does not change anything, since $\binom{4i+3-k}{m}=0$ when the upper index $4i+3-k<m$. We also set the lower limit of the inner sum to $m$ since $\binom{k}{m}=0$ if $k<m$ and $m>0$.

In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $k=0$.

In (4) we apply (1) accordingly and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

In (5) we apply the binomial series expansion.

In (6) we do some simplifications and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.

In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^{2m+1}$ and do some transformations.



That's beautiful, thanks. I need to learn generating functions approach myself, it looks very promising

@PetroKolosov: You're welcome. A great starter is for instance Herb Wilf's Generatingfunctionology

Let $n=i$.
We need to find the following sum:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{m=0}^n \sum\limits_k\binom{4n+3-k}{m}\binom{k}{m} \quad (1.0)
\end{align*}
Note that we can assume that $k$ goes over all integers without bounds.
We can rewrite the inner sum as
\begin{align*}
[x^{4n+3}]
    \sum\limits_{i,j} \binom{i}{m} x^i \binom{j}{m} x^j &= [x^{4n+3}] \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}} \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}} \quad (2.0) \\
    &= [x^{4n+3}] \frac{x^{2m}}{(1-x)^{2m+2}}
\end{align*}
which evaluates to
\begin{align*}
    \binom{4n+4}{2m+1} \quad (3.0)
\end{align*}
meaning that the sum is same as $S=\sum\limits_{m=0}^n \binom{4n+4}{2m+1}$.
Note that
\begin{align*}
    \binom{4n+4}{2m+1} = \binom{4n+4}{4n+4-(2m+1)} = \binom{4n+4}{2(2n+1-m)+1}
\end{align*}
Therefore, by substitution $m \to 2n+1-m$, we have
\begin{align*}
    S =\sum\limits_{m=0}^n \binom{4n+4}{2(2n+1-m)+1} = \sum\limits_{m=n+1}^{2n+1} \binom{4n+4}{2m+1}
\end{align*}
But this means that $2S = \sum\limits_{m=0}^{2n+1} \binom{4n+4}{2m+1} =2^{4n+3}$, which implies $S = 2^{4n+2}$. $\square$
P.S. Note that, more generally, it means that $\sum\limits_k  \binom{t-k}{m} \binom{k}{m} = \binom{t+1}{2m+1}$, so we have
\begin{align*}
    \sum\limits_{k=0}^t \binom{t}{k}_n = \sum\limits_{m=0}^n \binom{t+1}{2m+1}
\end{align*}
P.S.S. Also see this question for the identity above.

Thanks for the answer, gonna study it closely

Your prove is indeed correct. I have added equation numbering so that conversation become more clear.
In equation (2.0) by notation $[x^{4n+3}]$ means the coefficient of the $x^{4n+3}$ term in sum multiplications?
How exactly we get $\binom{4n+4}{2m+1}$ from $[x^{4n+3}] \frac{x^{2m}}{(1-x)^{2m+2}}$?

And why you decided to take precisely coefficient $[x^{4n+3}]$?

It is the coefficient near $x^{4n+3}$ because in the inner sum we used $x^i$ to mark binomials with $i=4n + 3 - k$ and $x^j$ to mark binomials with $j=k$. This way, in the sum over all $k$, it holds that $i+j = (4n+3-k)+k = 4n+3$, so overall we're only interested in the coefficients of $x^{4n+3}$.

$[x^{4n+3}] \frac{x^{2m}}{(1-x)^{2m+2}} = [x^{4n+3}] \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \binom{2m+1+i}{2m+1} x^{2m+i} = \binom{4n+4}{2m+1}$

The expansion $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \binom{i}{m} x^i = \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}}$ itself is standard.

This maybe a little aside from the problem you propose but my coauthor and I recently uploaded a preprint to Arvix which has a combinatorial proof of this conjecture (Corollary 2) of Gibbs and Miceli, Two Combinatorial Interpretations of Rascal Numbers.
The proof falls out from the fact that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}_i = \sum_{k=0}^{2i+1} \binom{n}{k}.$$
This identity has a fairly nice combinatorial proof using the interpretation of $\binom{n}{k}_i$ as counting the number of binary words of length $n$ with $k$ ones and at most $i$ ascents. Let $w = w_1 \ldots w_n$ be such a binary word then
$$
w \mapsto \begin{cases}
\operatorname{Des}(w) \cup \operatorname{Asc}(w) \cup \{ n \} & w_1 = 0 \\ 
\operatorname{Des}(w) \cup \operatorname{Asc}(w) & w_1=1
\end{cases}.
$$
Note that we are not taking the final position to be a descent as some authors do so $\operatorname{Des}(w) \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$ and $\operatorname{Asc}(w) \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$. Then, since $\operatorname{asc}(w) \le j$, we also have that $\operatorname{des}(w) \le j+1$ with equality only when $1 \in \operatorname{Des}(w)$ but this only occurs when $w_1 = 1$. So, this map always results in subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n \}$ with at most $2i+1$ elements. Furthermore, this map is invertible. Given a set $S \subseteq \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ with $|S| \le 2i+1$, we know the first letter of the it's corresponding $w$ by checking if $n \in S$. From here, we simply being by placing $1$s or $0$s (depending on whether $n \in S$ or not). If after placing $i$ bits, $i \in S$ then we switch to placing the bit (e.g. if we were placing $1$s, we switch the placing $0$s). After placing $n$ bits, we've reconstructed $w$. Thus, this map is a bijection which gives us our desired identity. Now, apply this result to $$\sum_{k=0}^{4i+3} \binom{4i+3}{k}_i = \sum_{k=0}^{2i+1} \binom{4i+3}{k} = 2^{4i+2}.$$
Hope this provides a new perspective!

Hi Amelia, sure I saw your work before, and even cited it in my own, take a look: https://kolosovpetro.github.io/pdf/IdentitiesInRascalTriangle.pdf ; It was hard time for me to understand proof in terms of combinatorics of binary words so I decided to find some algebraic proof of it, thanks to this MSE discussion we have it
